# Surjective function into Hartogs number of a set

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

For any set $A$, there is a surjective function $f:\mathcal{P}(A\times A)\longrightarrow\mathcal{H}(A)$. $\mathcal{H}(A)$ is the Hartogs number of $A$.

Proof attempt:

Suppose $R\subseteq A\times A$. Then either $R$ is a well-order, or it’s not. If $R$ is a well-order, then $R$ has the order type of a unique $\alpha_R$, where $\alpha_R$ is an ordinal number.

Define $f:\mathcal{P}(A\times A)\longrightarrow\mathcal{H}(A)$ by $f(R)=\alpha_R$ if $R$ is a well-order and $f(R)=0$ otherwise.

Checking that $f$ is a function is straightforward. Suppose $f(R)=\alpha$ and $f(R)=\beta$. If $R$ is not a well-order, then $f(R)=0=\alpha=\beta$. If $R$ is a well-order, then $\alpha_R$ is unique and $\alpha=\alpha_R=\beta=f(R)$.

To show $f$ is surjective, suppose $\alpha\in\mathcal{H}(A)$. We need to find an $R\in\mathcal{P}(A\times A)$ such that $f(R)=\alpha$. Here's where I'm having trouble. I know that since $\alpha\in\mathcal{H}(A)$, it must be an ordinal. It is not difficult to construct a well-ordered set isomorphic to $\alpha$. However, I am having a hard time constructing a well-ordered $\textbf{subset of $A\times A$}$ that is isomorphic to $\alpha$.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks for edit, Asaf. I did not realize that large cardinals was a topic for cardinals whose existence may or may not be established in ZFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $\alpha\in\mathscr{H}(A)$, there is an injection $h:\alpha\to A$, and you can use $h[\alpha]\subseteq A$ to construct an $R\subseteq A\times A$ such that $f(R)=\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'll need to think about why there is an injection from an element of the Hartogs number of A to A.

Comment: @Jay: You’re welcome! That’s actually one approach to defining the Hartogs number of a set; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number), for instance.

Comment: "If R is well-ordered" should be "If R can be well-ordered". And if it can,then there is a unique CARDINAL ordinal $|R|$.

Comment: @user254665: No, ‘if $R$ is well-ordered’ should be ‘if $R$ **is** a well-order’.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott. I see. I think the Q should be edited to make that perfectly clear.

Comment: @user254665: I thought that in context it was pretty clear despite the slightly sloppy terminology, but I’ve corrected it.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott. Follow up question: Can we show that |H(\alpha)| =/= |P(P(A\times A))| ?

Comment: @Jay: My first attempt here had an error, so I deleted it. I see that you’ve asked it as a separate question now (which is better anyway) and have responded there.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, now I see why there is an injection from an element of the Hartogs number of A to A. This is because every element of the Hartogs number of A is equipotent to some subset of A.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathcal{H}(A)$ is
a set of possible well-orderings of subsets of $A$, there is
$R\in P(A\times A)$ such that the order-type of $R=\beta$
for each $\beta\in\mathcal{H}(A)$. Let
$g(R)=$ the order-type of $R$ if $R$ is a well-ordering; otherwise $g(R)=0$. Then we have
a mapping of $P(A\times A)$ onto $\mathcal{H}(A)$
given by $R\mapsto g(R)$.