# Comparing Hartogs number to set of all sets of relations on a set

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Let $A$ be a set and let $\mathcal{H}(A)$ be the Hartogs number of $A$. Show that $|\mathcal{H}(A)|\neq|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A\times A))$.

Proof attempt: By contradiction. Suppose that $|\mathcal{H}(A)|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A\times A))|$. This would mean there is a bijective function $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A\times A))\longrightarrow\mathcal{H}(A)$. Now, here's where I'm getting stuck. My first thought is that if there was a bijection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A\times A))\longrightarrow\mathcal{H}(A)$, then that would mean that every set of relations on $A$ would be well-orderable. Is that the case? If not, please tell me where I'm going wrong and maybe give me a hint on what to try next?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $\mathscr{H}(A)=|\wp(\wp(A\times A))|$; then there is a bijection $$h:\mathscr{H}(A)\to\wp(\wp(A\times A))\;.$$ You already [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520301/surjective-function-into-hartogs-number-of-a-set) that there is a surjection $$f:\wp(A\times A)\to\mathscr{H}(A)\;.$$ You would then have a surjection

$$h\circ f:\wp(A\times A)\to\wp(\wp(A\times A))\;.$$